# Need help sorting with javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an assignment which asks me to load content from a database and be able to sort it by its separate field using javascript. My database runs fine but its the sorting part I'm having trouble with.

Here's an example of the results from a search of Cillian Murphy

```
<ul>
<li>
<h4>Title</h4>
<p>Sunshine</p>
<h4>Director</h4>
<p>Danny Boyle</p>
<h4>Lead Actor</h4>
<p>Cillian Murphy</p>
<h4>Year of Release</h4>
<p>2007</p>
<img src="http://cs1.ucc.ie/~jjam2/assignment/images/sunshine.jpg">
</li>

<li>
<h4>Title</h4>
<p>28 Days Later</p>
<h4>Director</h4>
<p>Danny Boyle</p>
<h4>Lead Actor</h4>
<p>Cillian Murphy</p>
<h4>Year of Release</h4>
<p>2002</p>
<img src="http://cs1.ucc.ie/~jjam2/assignment/images/28_days_later.jpg">
</li></ul>
```

Its pretty basic and I can conceptualise adding classes, getting the element by class, and sorting it by that element. But I've a feeling that it won't carry its related elements with it. Is this true or?

php for fetching from database as requested

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 
      if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name'])){ 
        $name=$_POST['name']; 
        //connect  to the database 
        $db=mysql_connect  ("host", "username",  "password") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error()); 
        //-select  the database to use 
        $mydb=mysql_select_db("database_name"); 
        //-query  the database table 
        $sql="SELECT  movie_id, movie_title, movie_director, movie_lead_actor, movie_YOR, movie_img FROM sci_fi_movies WHERE movie_title LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR movie_director LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR movie_lead_actor LIKE '%" . $name ."%'"; 
        //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
        $result=mysql_query($sql); 
        //-create  while loop and loop through result set 
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
              $Title      =$row['movie_title']; 
              $Director   =$row['movie_director'];
              $Actor      =$row['movie_lead_actor'];
              $Year       =$row['movie_YOR'];
              $Image      =$row['movie_img'];
              $ID         =$row['movie_id']; 
        //-display the result of the array 
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<h4>Title</h4><p>$Title</p>";
        echo "<h4>Director</h4><p>$Director</p>";
        echo "<h4>Lead Actor</h4><p>$Actor</p>";
        echo "<h4>Year of Release</h4><p>$Year</p>";
        echo "<img src=\"$Image\"></img>";
        echo "</li>";
      } 
    } else{ 
        echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
    } 
  } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: and why not sort it in the database query?

Comment: *"But I've a feeling that it won't carry its related elements with it. Is this true or?"* -- it depends entirely on the code you use to sort it. Since you haven't shown any, it's impossible to say.

Comment: You could easily search via the SQL, but if it has to be in JS, what do you need to sort by?

Comment: What is the data being returned by the server? JSON, XML...?

Comment: Can you show us how do you get the data from the server and construct that HTML you show on the question?

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to be JS. Ill be adding a button event handler to sort it by its different fields. ie: by director, title, date etc. basically all im asking is if its possible to keep its related elements with the sorted field?

Comment: Either return sorted data from the database (best), sort with PHP (good), or send the data to the browser and use JS (fine) to sort it before building the HTML. Sorting the elements when they're already on the page is hugely inefficient.

Comment: I understand that but its just the requirements of the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some class to your code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p class='title'>Sunshine</p>
        <h4>Director</h4>
        <p class='director'>Danny Boyle</p>
        <h4>Lead Actor</h4>
        <p class='actor'>Cillian Murphy</p>
        <h4>Year of Release</h4>
        <p class='year'>2007</p>
        <img src="http://cs1.ucc.ie/~jjam2/assignment/images/sunshine.jpg">
    </li>

    <li>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p class='title'>28 Days Later</p>
        <h4>Director</h4>
        <p class='director'>Danny Boyle</p>
        <h4>Lead Actor</h4>
        <p class='actor'>Cillian Murphy</p>
        <h4>Year of Release</h4>
        <p class='year'>2002</p>
        <img src="http://cs1.ucc.ie/~jjam2/assignment/images/28_days_later.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is the javascript

```
var DIR = 1; //direction 1 or -1
var mylist = $('ul');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
var field_class = 'actor';
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
return $(a).find('.'+field_class).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).find('.'+field_class).text().toUpperCase()) * DIR;
});
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6m3d7af7/

Note: if your list will get too large, you should consider ordering when fetching from DB

Comment: Wow, thats really cool. So I could just add buttons and change the field_class to the different classes to sort by that field right?

Comment: I used a button to trigger the event, but you can trigger it in the way you prefer. I added classes so that it is easier to understand, but you can also work with any child selector. And again, I set the `field_class` directly from JS, but you can set it from frontend with a radio button list, or dropdown or whatever you want